# How to set Samba smb url to the MediaRecorder.setFileOutput()

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that record video and save it on share folder that is on my PC. For that initially I record video and save it in mobile internal storage that successfully saved but now I want further step.

By using **jcifs samba library** I can access my share folder successfully and make a empty .mp4 file but when I pass the path to the **MediaRecorder.setOutputFile()** it crash the app and give me error **java.lang.IllegalStateException** but if I pass the internal storage path it working fine.

I searched a lot but solution not found. How to pass SMB URL path?

Comment: AFAIK, `MediaRecorder` only supports writing directly to the local filesystem.

Comment: so what i do for **saving/writing** file to remote location through **smburl**

Comment: Save locally, then copy it to the Samba share, I guess.

Comment: it is copy pasting but i want to directly saving the recorded video to remote location.

Comment: what are the ways to saving media files to the shared folder?

Comment: Did you try CommonsWare's suggestion? I assume you can do the final copy programmatically, you don't have to manually copy+paste it.